# Is there a good notion of dual sheaf in a family?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to S$ be a proper smooth morphism and let $E$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ which is flat over $S$ and has codimension $c$. The scheme $X$ might not be smooth, as well as $S$ might not be reduced, for instance.

> *Question*. Is there a good notion of dual of $E$ on the family $X/S$?

If $S$ were just $\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C$, we would take $E^\vee=\mathscr Ext^c_X(E,\omega_X)$. In general, for a smooth family $X\to S$, a natural guess could be $\mathscr Ext^c_X(E,\omega_{X/S})$. But I am not sure this is good enough, for instance: does it commute with taking fibers?

The situation I have in mind is a Hilbert scheme situation: I have a smooth proper variety $Y$ and $E=\mathscr O_V$ for some closed subscheme $V\subset X=Y\times S$, such that $V$ has codimension $c$ and is flat over $S$.

Under which condition does $\mathscr Ext^c_X(\mathscr O_V,\omega_{X/S})$ commute with base change?